# How to shift category axis and grid lines to be on a specific month for Amcharts stock chart V3

Tags: amcharts

The default behavior when using AmCharts stock chart using parseDates and dateFormats is to start on January when there are years of data. The grids start on January and if the dateFormats are changed from YYYY to MMM YYYY, I will get Jan 2014, Jan 2015.

What I need is to be able to set the grids to fall on a certain month and then labels to show that month also. For example, I create a report this month and the grid lines need to be on Oct months NOT January, and the labels should be Oct 2014, Oct 2015, and NOT Jan 2014 and Jan 2015.

I have this request from our marketing team who wants charts to show in this way. By showing grid lines from October to October, the grid lines show a more year to date spacing which is what they want clients focused on.

How is this possible using AmCharts Stock Chart V3?

Answer (score 0):

AmChart Support provided the answer.

```
"categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
        "gridAlpha": 0.0,
        "gridCount": 0,
        "minorGridEnabled": false,
        "labelsEnabled": false,
        "guides": historyGuide,
        "axisColor": "#DADADA",
        "dashLength": 1
    },
```

GridAlpha is set to zero so the default vertical gridlines don't show up. 
LabelesEnabled is false so the default labels don't show up
Guides is created that provide gridlines and labels (see below)

```
 var historyGuide = [
        {
            "date": "2017-10-2",
            "above": "true",
            "lineColor": "#dcddde",
            "lineAlpha": 0.7,
            "label": "Oct " + 2017,
        },
```

I found this approach to be the best vs the "addInitHandlers" option (see below):

```
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function (chart) {

        var yearsFound = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data_market.length; i++) {

            var day = (new Date(data_market[i].date)).getDate();
            var month = (new Date(data_market[i].date)).getMonth();
            var year = (new Date(data_market[i].date)).getFullYear();

            if (month == 9)
            {
                var isYearFound = yearsFound.find(item =>
                {
                    return item === year;
                });

                if (isYearFound == false || isYearFound == undefined) {
                    var guide = new AmCharts.Guide();
                    guide.date = data_market[i].date;
                    guide.above = true;
                    guide.lineColor = "#dcddde";
                    guide.lineAlpha = 0.7;
                    guide.lineThickness = 2;
                    guide.label = "Oct " + year;
                    chart.categoryAxis.guides.push(guide);
                    yearsFound.push(year);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Using addInitHandler caused a delay in page load computing a lot of chart points, and this caused issue during PDF generation. So, I found it best to generate the guides on the server side while generating in the html (for example via a .cshtml and a model).